# incrementing cells on a line in an array

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

Let's say I have a 100x100 array and I want to increment all the cells that would fall on the line that connect two points in the array by 1.

Does anyone have an algorithm or know of a library that can accomplish this?

I am working in PHP but pseudo code would be OK too.

Comment: What is "the line that connect two points in the array by 1"?

Comment: To expand on BoltClock's question, are you imagining square cells, and a line connecting a point in the center of one cell to a point in the center of another?

Comment: cells are squares. The line does not have to start or end in the center of a cell (but I might be able to simplfy it to that. Imagine drawing a line randomly across a sheet of squared paper. I want to determine which squares the line passed though.

Comment: Is this homework?  I can think of some practical uses, but the way the question is posed reads as an assignment question.

Comment: No its not. Its for plotting lines over a map for www.cyclistsroadmap.com

Comment: Right now its based on points which I don't like, I want to try and make it smoother. Here is an example of a tile now: http://www.cyclistsroadmap.com/main/getTile/139.5703125/35.60371874069731/139.74609375/35.746512259918504

Comment: Can you do diagonals, or are you in taxi cab geometry?

Comment: Diagonals. Just drawing a straight line from point A to Point B

Answer (score 3):

The best answer I have now is to find the bounding box of the start and end points and then check each of the cells in the bounding box and check the top right and bottom left corners to see if they are above or below the line.

If they are both above or both below then the line does not pass through the cell.

If one is above and the other is below then the line passes through the cell.

I'd also have to do the same check on the top left versus bottom right.

Does this algorithm seem sound?

Comment: I think this sounds good. You could optimize this by only checking those cells surrounding the last cell from which the line passed through, and stop checking the neighbors when you found the next cell the line passes through.

Comment: This algorithm is OK but the worst case scenario would wind up checking every box in the 100x100 array which is not good.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have a boundary, like in context of a maze, coupled with a start point and end point, there are a few ways you can go about coding an algorithm. Some good ones include:

1) Flood Fill, then find Shortest Path to the Destination node from the Start node.
2) Depth First Search from start to destination.

These are some of the common ones used in maze exploration and bounded grid exploration.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

If your 'line' is an actual line (the shortest distance between two points), and not a collection of random line segments, maybe you can use breadth first search like I did [here](http://brian-stinar.blogspot.com/2008/11/for-actionscript-with-incomplete.html). [This](http://brian-stinar.blogspot.com/2008/11/for-actionscript.html) helps explain what is going on a little bit more. This is only really applicable when the entire area is open. You may have to modify this if diagonals are OK, and you want to use PHP instead of ActionScript. The concepts might help you though.

However, if your line is not a line, but a squiggly drawing that starts and ends at a point, then you probably need to do an intersection test on your squares like you suggested.

I'm not sure if you will have multiple shortest paths with diagonals actually... I still think your bounding box solution, with optimizations, will probably work better, but I'm not sure if this would actually be wrong on any counts (with diagonals OK, and no obstacles.)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution which is more like a mathematical approach.

**Assumptions:**

- The 100X100 array is of the dimension 100 x 100 units where each cell occupies 1 x 1 unit.
- Moreover each point can be plotted with a max of a single significant digit after decimal for e.g. 2.9 units.
- The coordinate system is considered with the origin at Upper left corner and the max at Bottom right corner, which would match with the array indices.
- Let's consider the initial point as (x1,y1) and final point as (x2,y2).

**Mathematical Approach:**

- Find the slope of the line using the formula  m = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)
- Now find the equation of the line as y = m * x + b
- b can be found out by replacing y with y1 and x with x1.

**Algorithm:**

- Let us iterate through various values of x, with initial value as x1 and unitl x2. Tabulate y using the line equation and each iteration increment of x as 0.1
- Increment the value of the cell at initial point and also for every Array[floor(x),floor(y)].
- After each increment of the cell, increment the value of x by 1 and not 0.1

The only condition where this might be an issue is the case where the line has slope of infinity i.e a vertical line and a special case can be present for the same. I guess this should work :-)

Comment: I started writing this algorithm as my answer, but then realized that it doesn't always work. This is due to the impossibility to choose a correct step (the x increment you set to 0.1 in your algorithm). Imagine a case where the line is neither horizontal nor vertical, and cuts a cell very close to one of its corners. The closer to the corner the line passes, the smaller the length of the line included in the cell is. So that length can be smaller than 0.1 (or any step you might choose) and the cell might not be detected by your algorithm.

Comment: Ok to be more correct, you might be able to compute the optimal step for 2 given points. But still this step has no lower bound, so the complexity of the algorithm would have no upper bound...

Comment: @ Jules : True, that's the reason why I gave this as an assumption. Moreover instead of rawly choosing a step value we can do it based on 1/10th or 1/100th of the cell size. As you mentioned, more the fine tune more the accuracy :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think that a good (maybe the best) approach is to use the Bresenham's line algorithm

Take a look at: [Bresenham's line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm)